# Slick слайдер и Fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, fancybox

При инициализации слайдер, для того чтобы делать прокрутку слайдеров цикличной, создает дополнительные слайды клоны. Поэтому в фансибоксе отображаются 16 слайдов вместо 8. А параметр infinite: true нужен.
Это инициализация слайдера

```
$(".slider_3").not(".slick-initialized").slick({
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: true,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        infinite: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        speed: 1200,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 1240,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 900,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 630,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
              }
            }
          ]
    });
```

Вот HTML слайдера

```
                    <div class="slider_3">
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_25.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_25.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_26.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_26.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_27.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_27.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_24.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_24.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_25.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_25.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_26.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_26.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_27.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_27.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide">
                            <a href="img/362_24.jpg" class="sertificate" data-fancybox="fancybox_2" >
                                <div class="green-icon"></div>
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <img src="img/362_24.jpg" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <p>Managment System Certificate</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Нужно чтобы в Фансибоксе было четко столько слайдов сколько задано в HTML. Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать галерею не через `data-fancybox`

```js
//инициализируем галерею ДО запуска слайдера
var gallery = $('.slide a');
//при клике на ссылку в слайде запускаем галерею
$('.slide a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //узнаём индекс слайда без учёта клонов
  var totalSlides = +$(this).parents('.slider').slick("getSlick").slideCount,
      dataIndex = +$(this).parents('.slide').data('slick-index'),
      trueIndex;
  switch(true){
    case (dataIndex<0):
      trueIndex = totalSlides+dataIndex; break;
    case (dataIndex>=totalSlides):
      trueIndex = dataIndex%totalSlides; break;
    default: 
      trueIndex = dataIndex;
  }  
  //вызывается элемент галереи, соответствующий индексу слайда
  $.fancybox.open(gallery,{}, trueIndex);
  return false;
});

$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  customPaging: function() {
    return ''
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  padding: 15px;
}

.slider .slick-list {
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.slide {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.slide a {
  display: block;
}

.slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.slick-dots {
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 7px;
}

.slick-dots .slick-active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="http://www.placecage.com/c/1000/600">
      <img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/1000/600" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg/300px-Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg/300px-Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/9fdbf585d17c95f7a31ccacdb6466af9">
      <img src="https://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/9fdbf585d17c95f7a31ccacdb6466af9" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/50441-image/Hey-were-not-trying-to-pick-you-up-were-just-snapping-a-picture-using-Google-Glass.jpg">
      <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/50441-image/Hey-were-not-trying-to-pick-you-up-were-just-snapping-a-picture-using-Google-Glass.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/childrens-responsive-ichef-ck/400xn/amz/cbeebies/teletubbies-map-hero.jpg">
      <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/childrens-responsive-ichef-ck/400xn/amz/cbeebies/teletubbies-map-hero.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно для копий слайдов заменить атрибут data-fancybox на data-fancybox-trigger

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slick-cloned [data-fancybox]').each(function(){
        let attr = $(this).attr('data-fancybox');
        $(this).removeAttr('data-fancybox').attr('data-fancybox-trigger',attr);
    });
}, 300);
```